# What is the name of this eggplant dish that is similar to lasagna?

Tags: eggplant, lasagna

When I was at school I made an dish that was like a lasagna but replaced the pastry with Eggplant. It also had sliced bocconcini (I think) and was tomato based.

Just wondering if anyone knows the name of this dish? Is it just an Eggplant lasagna?

Answer (score 19):

In Italian we call it *parmigiana*.

Wikipedia says:

> Parmigiana or eggplant parmigiana (Italian: *melanzane alla parmigiana* or *parmigiana di melanzane*) is a Southern Italian dish made with shallow fried eggplant slices layered with cheese and tomato sauce, then baked. Variations made with breaded meat cutlets, such as veal and chicken parmigiana, have been developed in other countries, usually in areas of Italian immigration.

In Italy, you can find the variation with meatballs, but the original recipe (being from Southern Italy) doesn't include meat.

Comment: The eggplant version can also be breaded, with great results.

Answer (score 18):

I always thought of the Greek dish Moussaka as Eggplant Lasagna.  Except it is Béchamel sauce on top instead of more cheese.

Comment: Yeah I would have said Moussaka as well

Comment: moussaka is the actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be the stripped down version of eggplant parm that, oddly enough, eschews the parm. I've had it a couple times in Southern Italy. Essentially, it's just layers of eggplant (with the moisture salted out in a colander, then the rounds dredged and fried), roma tomato passata, bocconcini (or any fresh mozzarella), basil leaves and sea salt. It's baked and it's delicious.

Comment: What is "eggplant parm"?

Comment: @TFD: "Eggplant parm" is a common abbreviation of "eggplant parmesan." See [this other answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/6523/32904).

Answer (score 0):

The Italian dish is called Melanzane Parmigiana

Comment: Please do not repeat other answers

Comment: @JanDoggen : please give constructive criticism when people are trying to give good information but don't understand the site yet.  In this case, they can't vote up until they have 15 reputation, and they can't comment on other people's questions & answers until they're at 50.  So Charlie, thank you for corroborating what's already been said, but we try to keep duplicate answers (and questions) to a minimum.  Once you get some reputation from "good" (subjective) answers or questions, you'll be able to vote up to 'agree' with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen it called eggplant roulade

Comment: Wouldn’t “roulade” imply something “rolled”?